# Are "how to pronounce this programming related word/acronym/symbol" questions on topic for SO?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I came across [this pronunciation question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/178907/pronunciation-of-gerber) in the HNQ list and was surprised that the question appears to be on topic on electronics.SE since it wasn't closed and has upvotes.

I then searched SO for pronunciation questions, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=pronounce%20closed%3ano) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pronounce+closed%3Ayes).

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274022/how-do-i-pronounce-as-used-in-lambda-expressions-in-net) which seems to not be a basic how to say this word question and I think it's probably fine for SO.

However, a question [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761444/how-would-you-pronounce-qemu) I don't think would be on topic for SO since it could be primarily opinion based or better as a support question to whoever owns/runs the thing.

What are your thoughts on pronunciation questions?

Comment: I've close-voted the last two links as opinion based: _"Answers to those question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."_ How you'd call a operator like in the first one depends on what book you've learned about the operator, from.

Comment: @Cerbrus my problem with that is that questions like the qemu one would still be off topic if they were definitely answerable. Imagine qemu had a FAQ page telling people how it's supposed to be pronounced, that makes the question factually answerable - but it's still off topic as it is not about programming. It would maybe fit on english.SE, but it's not a good SO quesiton regardless of being factually answerable or not.

Comment: How you *write* a program in a way that makes the intent of the program clear to readers is a very common topic.  How you *talk* about a program in a way that listeners can understand is not fundamentally different.

Comment: @l4mpi: different reason, but still a close-vote then _*nods*_ What about _"How do I pronounce <operator>"_ questions? Hans: There are however multiple answers. Which one you'd use is a matter of personal (/workspace) preference.

Comment: @Cerbrus Sometimes there are multiple answers. Sometimes not. And even when there are multiple answers, there are still finitely many!

Comment: Is .gif pronounced "ghif" or "jif"?

Comment: @ryanyuyu: how is "ghif" pronounced?

Comment: @Cerbrus That's a very good example - could be phrased differently: should the `g` in gif be pronounced like girl or like george?

Comment: @assylias: Or like how us Dutch people pronounce "g"?

Comment: [This question on pronounciation of Haskell operators](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3242361/1048572) is definitively on topic imo, and has a clear and good answer.

Comment: If we are to pronounce that questions regarding pronunciation are off-topic, then perhaps we can also pronounce the [tag:pronunciation] tag dead too?

Answer (score 5):

I'd close-vote pronunciation questions as opinion based:

> **primarily opinion-based**
>   Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Questions like [How do I pronounce "=>" as used in lambda expressions in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274022/how-do-i-pronounce-as-used-in-lambda-expressions-in-net) are a good example.

It's gotten quite a few different answers, (nearly) all of which are (good) answers to the question, but none of them are *the* answer to the question, since it all depends on what book you learned about the operator, from.

Basically, how you'd call that operator depends on how it's used and what your personal preference is. As such, it's opinion based, and possibly even too broad.

What surprises me a lot, is how much votes it's gotten...

Comment: "What surprises me a lot, is how much votes it's gotten" Why? It's a standard bike-shed question, those are always popular unless nipped in the bud early enough.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Good point. I guess what surprises me more, then is that the question wasn't closed, yet. But then again, by '08 standards, that was a good enough question.

Comment: @Cerbrus: couldn't an answer that lists all acceptable pronunciations (and maybe some background on each) be considered _the_ answer?

Comment: @JSP64: Possibly, but then, that might be "Too broad", depending on the operator.

Comment: It's not opinion based. Pronunciation is part of the language and it's consensus-based, with several variants that can exist simultaneously. If I tell that I've heard `=>` being pronounced like this or that in conferences, it's not my opinion, I'm reporting a fact.

Answer (score 4):

Asking for canonical way of pronouncing a construct should be on-topic, asking "how would you pronounce this construct" - opinion based or edited into "canonical way to pronounce".

While strictly speaking closing as "opinion based" is a valid option, I think such questions have their place on SO similarly to "tools directly used by programmers for code". Yes, we use English to communicate a lot of things, but it is important to express code constructs in spoken way.

Here are a couple of samples that would greatly benefit from a canonical way of saying constructs:

C# sample: "x with that thingie from equal and greater returning x square"... (`x => x*x`)

C "I will return ampersand x" ( `return &x;`) - indeed should be "return *pointer to* x".

Answer (score 0):

Actually, pronunciation is probably off-topic--but the underlying associated concept with it might not be.

Often times, language itself used to describe language features often induces a certain mindset in a programmer. Take *"promises"*, for example--promises imply that the value will be *eventually, but surely* done. It's this connotation that is very important for conceptualizing a programming language or style's methodology and philosophy itself.

So, pronunciation itself might be "off-topic"--it's pedantic and relatively unimportant to the main idea that the way that we speak about and therefore think about the ways we think about the very basic building blocks of programming--"operators"--is very much on-topic. While even these ways of "conceptualizing" might not be set in stone, there are some metaphors that are widely-accepted and usually have a standard answer: *pointers* to places in memory